# Estimating joint probabilities across two datasets

Tags: regression, survey, joint-distribution

I would like to estimate the joint probability of two variables from two different surveys conditional on other variables that the two surveys have in common.

As an example I'm using data from this speed dating experiment [1] and the US Census microdata from 2004 [2].

Here is some code to illustrate:

```py
import pandas as pd

dating_raw = pd.read_csv(".../path/to/Speed Dating Data.csv", encoding='MacRoman')
pums2004_raw = pd.read_csv(".../path/to/ss04pus.csv", nrows=100000, usecols=["SEX", "AGEP", "RAC1P", "JWTR", "HISP"])

dating = pd.concat([
    dating_raw.age,
    dating_raw.gender.map({0: "female", 1: "male"}).rename("sex"),
    dating_raw.race.map({1: "black", 2: "white", 3: "hispanic", 4: "asian-pi", 5: "native", 6: "other"}),
    dating_raw.go_out.map({
        1: "Several times a week",
        2: "Twice a week",
        3: "Once a week",
        4: "Twice a month",
        5: "Once a month",
        6: "Several times a year",
        7: "Almost never",
    }),
], axis=1)

pums = pd.concat([
    pums2004_raw.AGEP.rename("age"),
    pums2004_raw.SEX.map({1: "male", 2: "female"}).rename("sex"),
    pums2004_raw.RAC1P.map({1: "white", 2: "black", 3: "native", 4: "native", 5: "native", 6: "asian-pi", 7: "asian-pi", 8: "other", 9: "other"}).rename("race"),
    pums2004_raw.JWTR.map({
        1: "Car, truck, or van",
        2: "Bus or trolley bus",
        3: "Streetcar or trolley car",
        4: "Subway or elevated",
        5: "Railroad",
        6: "Ferryboat",
        7: "Taxicab",
        8: "Motorcycle",
        9: "Bicycle",
        10: "Walked",
        11: "Worked at home",
        12: "Other method",
    }).rename("transport"),
], axis=1,)

pums.loc[pums2004_raw.HISP > 1, "race"] = "hispanic"
```

`dating` looks like this:

| age | sex | race | go_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | male | white | Twice a week |
| 23 | female | other | Several times a week |
| 28 | female | asian-pi | Twice a week |
| 31 | female | black | Several times a week |

`pums` looks like this:

| age | sex | race | transportation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | male | hispanic | Worked at home |
| 26 | female | white | Car, truck, or van |
| 15 | female | black | Motorcycle |

How can I estimate the chance that an asian male over 25 goes out several times a week **AND** travels to work by any method other than by car/truck/van? *I **do not** think that it is appropriate to assume that going out and mode of transportation are independent.* How can I make use of additional variables that appear on both surveys to improve the estimate? What are the pitfalls?

$$
P(go\_out=Several times a week, transport ~= Car, truck or van | race=asian, sex=male, age>25) = ?
$$

[1] https://data.world/annavmontoya/speed-dating-experiment

[2] https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/data/pums/2004/csv_pus.zip

Comment: This problem falls into the area of "statistical data integration." However, it will be quite challenging to estimate a joint distribution when there are zero observations that have measurements for both of your variables of interest: the only way to estimate a joint distribution is to make some very strong assumptions, in which case your analysis will be mostly circular reasoning. But here's a good general open-access reference on statistical data integration for survey data: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42081-020-00093-w

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are out of luck here. Although you have extra variables sec, race and age, you cannot reconstruct how go_out and transportation relate to each other without making extra assumptions. The data were certainly not measured on the same persons.

Example: Denote the two variables that interest you as A and B. For sake of simplicity assume that A has three levels and B has two levels.  To get the chance that an asian male over 25 does A and B, you would extract all asian males over 25. Let us say there are only 7 individuals, and for variable A you count number of outcomes in levels: #$A_1=4$, #$A_2=2$ and #$A_3=1$ and for B, $B_1=3$, $B_2=4$. Then you cannot find out how many of them had a particular combination $A_i,B_j$; there are many possible combinations of joint outcomes with same marginal distribution, for example

|  | A1 | A2 | A3 |  | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **B1** | 2 | 1 | 0 |  | 3 |
| **B2** | 2 | 1 | 1 |  | 4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **sum** | 4 | 2 | 1 |  | 7 |

or

|  | A1 | A2 | A3 |  | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **B1** | 0 | 2 | 1 |  | 3 |
| **B2** | 4 | 0 | 0 |  | 4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **sum** | 4 | 2 | 1 |  | 7 |